# Combine two simple objects to a list

Tags: terraform

I was wondering if anyone could suggest a trick to do this. Imagine I have a terraform code that retrieves the latest version of multiple AMI.

```
data "aws_ami" "amzn" {
  most_recent = true
  owners      = ["amazon"]

  filters...
}

data "aws_ami" "centos" {
  most_recent = true
  owners      = ["12345678"]

  filters...
}
```

What I would like to have is a list with both AWS AMi. The purpose is to choose between the two when I create an EC2 instance.

```
resource "aws_instance" "EC2" {
  count                = 100
  ami                  = choose from list
  instance_type        = "t2.micro"
...
}
```

In this example, I have provided only two AMI. But in reality I will have about 20.

Answer (score 1):

How a list will help you? You need to choose from it somehow. It's better to use a map for it, so you can pick a specific ami based on a *key*.

After you load the data resources, you can define a *map* using [`locals`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/locals.html):

```
locals {
    amis = {
        amzn = data.aws_ami.amzn
        centos = data.aws_ami.centos
    }
}
```

Then to access it, you simply address it as follows

```
resource "aws_instance" "EC2" {
  count                = 100
  ami                  = local.amis[amzn].id
  instance_type        = "t2.micro"
...
}
```

Comment: You can access list using [index]. So you mean it's impossible using a list?

Comment: Yea but if you have 20 ami's, you'll need to remember what each index refers to. It's much simpler with a map, but if you want to use `local.amis[index].id` , that will work too.